# Which class need to be injected in Bamboo plugin to get diff in Pull Request?

Tags: java, api, bamboo, atlassian-plugin-sdk

I've created project using:

```
atlas-create-bamboo-plugin
```

I'm trying to get diffs (or commit list) on current build. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It might not be the easiest way to get release notes, but as part of a deployment step you can generate a URL with commits between this and the previous release. By querying the release note URL, you can get each commit message.

```
@Scanned
public class ReleaseNoteTask implements DeploymentTaskType {

    private static final String BAMBOO_URL = "https://bamboo.url"; // URL to bamboo

    @Override
    public TaskResult execute(DeploymentTaskContext taskContext) {
        final TaskResultBuilder taskResultBuilder = TaskResultBuilder.newBuilder(taskContext);
        final BuildLogger buildLogger = taskContext.getBuildLogger();

        long versionId = taskContext.getDeploymentContext().getDeploymentVersion().getId();
        String deploymentProjectId = taskContext.getCommonContext().getEntityKey().toString().split("-")[0];

        String releaseNotesPath = BAMBOO_URL + "/deploy/viewDeploymentVersionCommitsSnippet.action?pageSize=-1&versionId=" + versionId + "&deploymentProjectId=" + deploymentProjectId + "&decorator=nothing&confirm=true&os_authType=basic";

        // You can use a library like jsoup to read HTML from releaseNotesPath and parse each commit message

        buildLogger.addBuildLogEntry("Release notes: " + releaseNotesPath);

        return taskResultBuilder.success().build();
    }
}
```